# Keras prediction returns such small values

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm a beginner of neural networks. I created a neural network to recognize the ears of 15 targets (classes). The dataset is composed of 300 images and divided into "training", "validation" and "test". For each class in the training there are 13 images, for validation 3 and for the test 4.

This is the structure of the network

```
input_shape = (128, 128, 3)
NUM_CLASSES = 15
BATCH_SIZE = 32
NUM_EPOCHE = 50

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = input_shape, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dropout(.5))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(.5))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = NUM_CLASSES, activation = 'softmax'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

classifier.fit_generator(
training_set,
steps_per_epoch = 6,  
epochs = NUM_EPOCHE,
validation_data = validation_set,
validation_steps = 2, 
)
```

I believe that the number of epochs is very high but if I try to decrease it the accuracy decreases. Anyway, when I try to predict an image taken from the test set, I get very small values as a result. I don't know why this happens. I need values between 0 and 1. I don't know if it's a problem due to the structure of the model or what.

```
x = image.load_img('dataset_biometria/ear/test_set/15/02_15_06.jpg',      target_size=(128,128))
x = image.img_to_array(x)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)
x = x/255
predictions = classifier.predict_proba(x, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
print(predictions)
```

This is the result of prediction:

```
[[5.6861238e-05 2.6912585e-02 5.8105786e-04 1.7117772e-03 1.5182612e-03
1.5271029e-01 3.7086603e-01 3.7264896e-03 1.0833447e-03 8.4272223e-03
2.5183004e-03 5.6781149e-03 3.8425636e-02 3.8328120e-01 2.5028707e-03]]
```

Comment: Use `np.argmax` to get the highest scoring among all the classes, and that's your highest probability prediction and its probability.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be, all the values are between zero and one, and sum to one, this is produced by the softmax function, so there is no problem here, just a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

What you got are the per class probabilities. And if you sum up the values, the result will be 1.0 which is expected. For example:

```
per_class_probabilities = [[5.6861238e-05, 2.6912585e-02, 5.8105786e-04, 1.7117772e-03, 1.5182612e-03, 1.5271029e-01, 3.7086603e-01, 3.7264896e-03, 1.0833447e-03, 8.4272223e-03, 2.5183004e-03, 5.6781149e-03, 3.8425636e-02, 3.8328120e-01, 2.5028707e-03]]
print(np.sum(per_class_probabilities))
# 1.0
```

Then, if you want to get the most probable class i.e the prediction:

```
class_prediction = np.argmax(per_class_probabilities)
print(class_prediction)
# 13
```

Comment: Why, if I reduce the number of epoch, do I get a tremendously larger number for each class?

Comment: If you sum up the probabilities they will always be equal to 1. So, I don't know what you mean by getting tremendously large number for each class.